# App Service not returning full certificate chain with custom TLS binding

Tags: azure, ssl, certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I uploaded a self signed certificate chain in .pfx format to our App Service instance and configured SNI TLS/SSL Binding. For some reason only the server certificate with depth 0 is returned although I would expect the intermediate and root cert as well.
Has anyone else encountered this behaviour? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the Tech-Support at Microsoft, i have been told it is not possible to return full self-signed certificate chains via App Service for security reasons. It is however possible to use Application Gateway for SSL offload with self signed certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same issue. The answer given to you by Microsoft support seems very strange and illogical, there can't be any security issue with returning the whole chain. I see that one particular App Service of mine returns only its leaf cert, while others happily present the whole chain.

Maybe support guys were just too lazy to dig deeper.

Do you remember, was your App Service hosted on [ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/overview) or not? And if it was, on what version of ASE?